# Matching document by ElasticSearch's Percolate API always returns no matches if registered queries contain terms

Tags: python, elasticsearch, pyelasticsearch

I try to use `Percolator` by `Elasticsearch` and I have a minor issue.

Suppose our document looks like this:

```
{
    "doc": {
        "full_name": "Pacman"
        "company": "Arcade Game LTD",
        "occupation": "hunter", 
        "tags": ["Computer Games"]
    }
}
```

And our registered query like this:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
               {
                   "match_phrase":{
                       "occupation":  "hunter"
                   }
               },
               {
                   "terms": {
                       "tags":  [
                           "Computer Games",
                           "Electronic Sports"
                           ],
                       "minimum_match": 1
                   }
               }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I get:

```
{
   "took": 3,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "total": 0,
   "matches": []
}
```

and I don't know what I'm doing wrong, because if I remove `terms` from registered query and just match by `occupation` it works as expected and I get one match.

Any hints?

**Update 1**

OK, I think that @Slam's solution is the right direction, but I still have some issues:

I updated my mapping for tags, so it now looks like this:

```
"tags": {
    "store": True,
    "analyzer": "snowball",
    "type": "string",
    "index": "analyzed",
    "fields": {
        "raw": {
           "type": "string",
           "index": "not_analyzed"
       }
    }
}
```

New document to percolate:

```
{
    "doc": {
        "full_name": "Pacman"
        "company": "Arcade Game LTD",
        "occupation": "hunter", 
        "tags.raw": ["Computer Games"]
    }
}
```

And when I try to match document above with `tags.raw`, still no matches are found.
I analyzed field `tags.raw` but it looks like it still creates tokens `computer`, `games` and `running`.

Comment: Er... "Computer Games" is neither "Computer Software" nor "Electronic Sports"? )

Comment: Yeah, sorry, this is not the actual example and I just inserted dummy values. Anyway, we assume, that at least one tag should match. Thanks for correction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess, you use implicit mapping (default analyzer) or any type of analyzer for your `tags` field. That means, that data ("Computer Games" in your case) is broken to token parts and no longer available for terms search, as now its represented as something like `computer+game` in index.

To be able to do term matching for strings, you need either map them as non-analyzed (to prevent them to be sliced to tokens) like

```
PUT so/pacman/_mapping
{
  "pacman": {
    "properties": {
      "tags": {
        "type": "string",
        "index": "not_analyzed"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

or make your `tags` field [multi-field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.6/mapping-core-types.html#_multi_fields_3), like

```
PUT so/pacman/_mapping
{
  "pacman": {
    "properties": {
      "tags": {
        "type": "string",
        "index": "analyzed",
        "fields": {
          "raw": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and query documents with

```
GET so/pacman/_search
{
  "query": {
    "terms": {
      "tags.raw": [
        "Computer Games",
        "Running"
      ],
      "minimum_match": 1
    }
  }
}
```

Such approach let you perform text search *and* term searches.

According to your **Update 1**, after you've put the correct mapping and percolator like:

```
PUT so/.percolator/1
{
  "query": {
    "terms": {
      "tags.raw": [
        "Computer Games",
        "Maze running"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

you need to index/percolate documents with format like

```
GET so/pacman/_percolate
{
  "doc": {
    "full_name": "Pacman",
    "company": "Arcade Game LTD",
    "occupation": "hunter", 
    "tags": ["Computer Games"]
  }
}
```

What is happening here. You're indexing/percolation document with field `tags` (without any mention of `raw` or whatever multifield you have). ES take this field from json, adds `tags.raw` to index (as whole string), and at the same time brake it down to analyzed tokens, and put them in `tag` field (the process is much more complicated, but lets pass it for the sake of simplicity here). So, you don't need to manage any internal things about this field, you've done that in your mapping.

And when percolator works, it will look for `tags.raw` field in index (because you created terms query for this "subfield") leaving the analyzed one untouched.

Comment: Thanks, can you look at my first update in the original question?

Comment: Must be the other way around, in percolate query use the raw field and in the doc provide the normal field.

Comment: @JettroCoenradie is this meant for Update 1 in original question or is this meant for this answer?

Comment: @primoz Updated answer according to that. Just pass document as usual, don't think about `raw` multifield. You've done your work putting mapping, elastic will do the rest for you

Comment: OK, i changed back to original document. But I can't create percolator, because it throws error: `Strict field resolution and no field mapping can be found for the field with name [tags.raw]]`. I use mapping specified in my updated answer.

Comment: @Primoz seems that there's some misleading in your code. Try to recreate problem step-by-step. Check out this gist https://gist.github.com/3lnc/f02b8d2993c8a3ba11e2 (syntax is for marvel/sense, but I guess you'll got the idea)

Comment: @Slam Indeed, I had one curly bracket at the wrong position in my mappings. It works now. Thanks for your help!